# How do I add turtles to an existing fish tank

Tags: fish

I have a typical 10 gal fish tank with Neon Tetras and one algae eater.

I'd like to add two small turtles.

Besides a place for them to rest are there any issues I should be aware of or precautions I should take?

Answer (score 4):

A 10gal tank is to small for all turtles I know.

Next point is: all turtles do not like to live with other turtles.  Only to make baby turtles they like  to meet. Rest of the year they live alone.

Turtles tank minimale have to be long as 7 times the shell length and wide as 2-3 shell lengths (so the turtle could turn around comfortly). The high of the water have to be between one and two shell length. One minimum because the turtle need to hide under water, maximum two for sleeping (reach the air on surface with nose standing on the ground without swimming).

If you have little turtles for your little tank, the fish will not be happy with the turtle friendly water high. If the turtle is big enough for fish friendly water high your tank is not long and wide enough.

Another point will be: turtles grow their whole life. So you have to change your tank in assumed a half year against a bigger one. Red eared sliders for example grow to a size  (shell!) of a toilet seat. (How all "Trachemys" turtles) So in the end you need an approximated 250gal tank.

And another another point: most turtles will eat your fish while they grow up. They are fast hunters especially if the fish are "beautyful" ones with long fins.

Last point: turtles make more dirt than fish. You need approximated 3 times the power of a "normal" filter. (For example you need a 90gal filter for 30gal real water).

**So in summary** I suggest to not add turtles to a fish tank. But if you really want, you could make a turtle tank and add fish to it.

I have one 20cm turtle with 10 sumatra barbs in a 1000l/~260gal tank in the moment. But I had combined succsessfull the same turtle with one gold fish and some guppies. Guppies are good idea because they have much and more babies and gold fish and turtle hold a stable count.