# Small Bog Turtles for a 36 gallon (136 liter) bowfront aquarium

Tags: turtles

I was researching small turtles that could live in my 36 gallon (136 liter) bowfront aquarium (link here: [petsmart](https://www.petsmart.com/fish/tanks-aquariums-and-nets/aquariums/top-fin-bowfront-aquarium-and-stand-ensemble---36-gallon-54980.html?fmethod=Search) )and I came across a small species called bog turtles. Their adult size is mostly 4 inches but some reach only three inches. Does anyone know if I can get this type of turtle?

Comment: *"The bog turtle (Glyptemys muhlenbergii) is a critically endangered species"* (from Wikipedia). So please refrain from contributing to their extinction. There are countless other pets you can have which are more suitable and far from being extinct.

Comment: *"I was researching"* - that was not a research, if you did not find that those little creatures are almost all dead. Also, they are not deep-water creatures. Why did you consider that a deep aquarium is a good place for them?

Comment: @virolino could be a translation issue, I first was remindet to the German "Höckerschildkröte"... Also in some countries endangered species are not this known as in yours and mine

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Would you please add the latin name of the turtle you speak about (if it is not the one virolino guessed)?

Comment: If it was not a translation issue, and you search for an alternative, not endangered species, I could recommend this one: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graptemys Depending of the subspecies they are in the same rangw as you want them

Comment: And have a look into this question, to learn about turtles in fish tanks :)   https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26691/how-do-i-add-turtles-to-an-existing-fish-tank

Comment: I just searched the name of the turtle provided, and the info was there - that it is endangered. I cannot know what was the intended name of the turtle - so your comment to add the latin name (or a link to some site) would be good.

Comment: Considering that the bog turtle is critically endangered, and would only be able to be acquired on the black market, I would venture that no, this is absolutely not a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog_turtle), the Bog Turtle (Glyptemys muhlenbergii) is critically endangered and protected by the Endangered Species Act. They are not bred in captivity for pets; any that are sold as pets have been poached from their natural habitats and are being [sold illegally](https://web.archive.org/web/20100723012012/http://www.fws.gov/nc-es/reptile/bogtur.html) on the black market.

**You cannot legally purchase or own a bog turtle**, and doing so will damage their populations and encourage further poaching. Even if one was found on the black market, it would be extremely high priced due to the nature of the trade and the turtle's rarity as a critically threatened species.